# AngularJS HTML input file restricting to file formats in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, safari, internet-explorer-8

I am using below code to restrict user to upload file formats i.e. in upload dialogue he will be able to see only those particular files.

type="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.jpe,.jfif,.tif,.tiff,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.csv"

It works fine in Chrome, Mozilla and IE9 and above. But this is not working in IE8 and Safari.

How can I restrict in IE8 and Safari?

Comment: I was going through this link : http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/14-file.html but seems I can't modify it for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it's better to check by mime type rather than file extension, as the name of the file can be changed to anything. This is also the standard for the accept property.

For your example in particular, you'd want to do something like this instead:

`<input type="file" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/excel,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/tiff,image/x-tiff" />`

If you want more flexibility, you can also do stuff like `accept="image/*,video/*"` to accept all image and video types.

See [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) for a list of mime types and their corresponding file extensions.

Comment: its working when I used accept="application/pdf" but when I apply value from JSON Object it is showing as ".application/pdf". I am loading accept value from JSON Object and like allowedextension=['pdf'] and then on page as accept={{allowedextension}} and finally its injecting as accept=".aaplication/pdf"

Comment: Hmmm, as far as i can tell you should be able to do <input type="file" accept="{{allowedextension}}" /> as long as in your controller you have $scope.allowedextension = "application/pdf";

Comment: I used the same. But when page is rendered it is coming as accept=".application/pdf" which of which this particular accept is not working instead of this if I directly insert into page as accept="application/pdf" then it works fine. I don't know how DOM is rendered in this case and extra character "." is coming :(